# why custom path for output pdfs in rmarkdown pdf?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex

Is there to generate output pdfs generated in different location

```
rmarkdown::render('Rd.Rmd', output_dir = '../pdfs/')
```

when i checked in i got above line of code i tried to use it but unable to generate pdf in specified location. Is the one is the correct way.

i'm getting this error

```
error in parse block (g[-1],g[1]):Duplicate chunk label 'setup' which has been used for chunk
```

Comment: I use `output_dir` to specify the folder and `output_file` to specify the file name.  It's all in the online docs.

Comment: ```rmarkdown::render('td.Rmd', output_dir = '../pdfs/',output_file = 'td.pdf')``` is this correct i'm using in rcode chunk. still i'm not able to generate

Answer (score 1):

placing near title, and output at top works for me

```
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, output_dir = "../pdf") })
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me and reports problems relating to missing folders.

```
rootFolder <- "./validation"
dateString <- format(lubridate::today(), "%Y-%m-%d")
outputFolder <- paste0(rootFolder, "/", dateString)

if (dir.exists(outputFolder)) {
  print(paste0("Output folder [", outputFolder, "] exists..."))
  fileName <- paste0("/validationReport_", site, "_", dateString)
  print(paste0("Writing validation report to ", fileName, " ..."))
  rmarkdown::render(
    input=paste0(rootFolder, "/validationReportTemplate.Rmd"),
    output_file=fileName,
    output_dir=outputFolder,
    params=list(siteID=site)
  )
} else {
  print(paste0("Ooops!  Output folder [", outputFolder, "] does not exist!"))
}
```

You have a trailing delimiter at the end of `output_dir`.  I don't.  Apart from that, your syntax looks good.

Have you checked that the input file and the output folder exist?